# Получение ссылок на картинки с чужой страницы

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста как решить поставленную задачу. Есть страничка, как я могу получить ссылки на нужные мне картинки с этой странички? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Посмотрите код HTML. `<img src="адрес расположения картинки" />`

Comment: Та нее,мне сотни игроков в базу надо вносить я же не буду просматривать каждого html разметку и искать ссылки! Было бы так все просто не просил бы совета на форуме)

Answer (score 3):

Используйте библиотеку PHP [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) для парсинга HTML.

Изображения вытягиваются как то так:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://angelscity.combats.com/inf.pl?1144788114');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

Comment: Спасибо большое попробую